# can a figure tag be a fancybox link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, fancybox

Can I make a figure tag a fancybox link there is no content just a background image. I know its not good practice I just wonder wether or not it can be done?

```
 <figure class="apear"><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="some content here"></a></figure>
```

Thanks

Comment: i have and it didn't work, i just wanted to know if this is always the way or if I am doing something stupidly wrong

Answer (score 1):

Any element can be used to trigger fancyBox. Just add "data-fancybox-href" attribute. Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Y74fs/

```
<figure class="fancybox" data-fancybox-href="1_b.jpg" data-fancybox-title="Simple title"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt=""/></figure>
```

and then

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and it was very simple, there was nothing there to link from so I added the source of a transparent .png image and made that the link.

```
<figure class="apear"><a class="fancybox" href="image.jpg"><img src="img/transparentlink.png" width="100%" height="100%"></a></figure>
```